# Spliced array in Javascript is irregular

Tags: javascript, arrays, array-splice

I'm trying to splice an array when an element is clicked. When I console.log the new array it's irregular and sometimes removes the wrong array element and the last index will never be removed. Any one here with a good explanation to this?

```
var container = document.getElementById('container'),
notDone = document.getElementsByClassName('notDone'),
deleting = document.getElementsByClassName('delete'),
div,
remove,
i,
toDo = [
'One',
'Two',
'öäå'],


for(i = 0; i < toDo.length; i++){
    div = document.createElement('div');
    div.innerHTML = toDo[i];
    div.className = 'notDone';
    remove = document.createElement('div');
    remove.innerHTML = '<p>Remove</p>';
    remove.setAttribute("data-id", i);
    remove.className = 'delete';

    container.appendChild(div);
    div.appendChild(remove);

    notDone[i].addEventListener('click', function(){

        if(this.classList.contains('notDone')){
            this.className = 'done';
        }else{
            this.className = 'notDone';
        }
    });

    deleting[i].addEventListener('click', function(event){
        event.stopPropagation();
        var shouldDelete = this.getAttribute("data-id");
        console.log('va' + shouldDelete);
        toDo.splice(shouldDelete, 1);
        this.parentNode.remove();
        console.log(toDo);
    });
}
var check = document.getElementById('check');
check.addEventListener('click', function(){
    console.log(toDo + ' checking array')
});
```

Comment: The question is, why would `this.getAttribute("data-id")` return an array, and not a string ?

Comment: @adeneo: `toDo` is the array, `shouldDelete` is an integer string.

Comment: That is a good question that Im not able to answer, I'm new to JS and still learning. Any thoughts on how I should solve this problem?

Comment: @Bergi - my eyesight is going ..........

Comment: I guess it happens because you never update the original index, so after you remove the second element (data-id=1) the former third one (data-id=2) moves to the second position. If you click on it, it will report itself as having data-id=2, and you'll splice the current third element (data-id=3).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> it sometimes removes the wrong array element

The problem you are facing is that the `data-id` is storing a fixed index, yet the `toDo` array is mutable. When you remove an element from the array, all the indices behind it become invalid. For example when you `.splice(0, 1)`, then you cannot do `splice(2, 1)` any more because the array has only two items left.

> the last index will never be removed.

It would, if you clicked the last element at first.

---

What you can do instead is either

- not removing the indices from the `toDo` array (and cutting the whole array), but just set the array values to `null`; or
- not store the original indices, but the values that you want to remove, and search them (using `indexOf`) in the current array every time you remove an element